# Can Lattice objects be non-equidistant initially?

Tags: lattice

Lattice objects modify meshes as soon as they are applied. Let's say i want to have 3 as the value for U and the middle subdivision of the lattice should not be in the middle initially, but more to the one side. This should not affect the coupled mesh as i want to modify it in a later shape key. Is there a way to modify the shape of the lattice to be not equidistant?

How Blender initializes a lattice object

[image: Lattice object with equidistant basis shape key]

How Blender reacts on modification of the initial state

[image]

How i want the initial state of the lattice object

[image]

Comment: From docs: *"The lattice should be scaled and moved to fit around your object in Object Mode. Any scaling applied to the object in Edit Mode will result in the object deforming. This includes applying scale with Ctrl-A as this will achieve the same result as scaling the lattice in Edit Mode, and therefore the object."*

Comment: Does it help to use 5 as value for U? Should be possible to achieve the same thing you want to do...

Comment: If you want to change multiple points like you described it, you could use mesh-deform.

Comment: Click on the eye icon on the latice modifer, it will turn off the modifier temporarily, adjust the lattice and then turn the modifier back on.